# Woo Commerce Variations

Tags: plugins

I've got what would appear to be a simple site setup.

I've got an item:

The ABC Cell Phone (available in TWO COLORS)
add a charger for $5.00
add a case for $5.00
add a screen protector for $5.00
add (well, you get the idea, add some accessories)

When I do this in variations I have to calculate the math for all of those products and variations by hand, is there a simple way to do this?

Previously, with other carts, I was able to just add an item and checkbox and it would calculate with the order.

I've paid out $$$$ for extensions that don't seem to cut it.  The import/export suite would require some kind of spreadsheet magic I can't put my mind around to update all of the variations for my import file with a simple price change of ONE item.

### This variation scheme doesn't make much sense to me... Seems like a ton of manual updating for something that should be pretty simple.

I've also got another little thing I'm trying to figure out.
We do embroidery for $5.00 a line.  Max 2 lines.
So, is there an easy way to have the customer enter their info in a TXT Box that sizes to the embroidery standard sizes?

12 characters for large letters
15 characters for medium letters
20 characters for small letters

You'd think that would be just a simple plugin?  Any hints?  Anyone?

Comment: That are two separate questions. And I am afraid you will not get answers for something so localized.

Answer (score 1):

In most e-commerce carts variations are exactly that; variations of a product. For example a shirt available in small, medium, large and also available in different colors red, blue, and green. In this example you'd have:

1. Shirt, small, red
2. Shirt, medium, red
3. Shirt, large, red
4. Shirt, small, blue
5. Shirt, medium, blue
6. Shirt, large, blue
7. Shirt, small, green
8. Shirt, medium, green
9. Shirt, large, green

What you're asking for may be better suited for the WooCommerce grouped products instead, since these aren't actually variations of a single product. More a *grouping* of products.

As for the custom input it's not available in the default WooCommerce as far as I know. But I did a quick Google search and found this hack:

[Comment thread on WooCommerce](http://ideas.woothemes.com/forums/133476-woocommerce/suggestions/2287164-new-woocommerce-extension-custom-product-form-fi)

[Code on gethub:gist](https://gist.github.com/1321675)

A bit of searching online may find other alternatives.

Comment: +1 for the variations point. Accessories cannot be variations, but a group of products!

Answer (score 0):

Try the Product Addons extension for WooCommerce - it'll let you add custom fields and pricing to product pages. So for example, you could add a checkbox that says "Add a charger, $5.00" and when someone checks that box and adds the item to the cart the $5 extra will be added to the base price of the product.

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you provided a link as well in your answer.

Comment: http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/